# Signs of a point of intersection between a paraboloid and tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I've calculated the value in the subject line but I get signs opposite to the professor.

The original question is

> find the point on the paraboloid $$z = 4x^2 + y^2$$ at which the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $$x + 2y + z = 6.$$

Since the tangent plane and parallel plane will have parallel gradient vectors, and the paraboloid will have the same gradient vector as the tangent plane at the point in question, I want to find the general gradient vector of each and set them equal to find $x/y/x$.
$<1,2,1>$. Setting those equal, I get $x = 1/8$ and $y = 1$. To find $z$, I use the paraboloid equation, so $z = 4(1/8)^2 + 1^2 = 17/16$. Finally, the point is $$(1/8, 1, 17/16).$$

However, my instructor gets the point $(-1/8,-1,17/16)$. Does anyone see where I screwed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal vector to the paraboloid at $x,y$ is $(8x,2y,-1)$, the normal vector to the plane is $(1,2,1)$.

These two vectors are parallel to each other if the following vector pruduct is zero
$$\begin{bmatrix}
i&j&k\\
1&2&1\\
8x&2y&-1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-2-2y\\
1+8x\\
2y-16x
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
.$$
So, $2+2y=0$ and $$y=-1,$$ $1+8x=0$ and $$x=-\frac18,$$ and $2(-1)-16(-\frac18)=0.$ As a result $$z=\frac 4 {64}+1=\frac{17}{16}.$$

*You were having a sign error.*